# Amazon SES - Send HTML mail through PHP sdk

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email using amazon ses PHP sdk.

I got the following code. Working Fine

```
$body = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";


require_once('ses.php');
$ses = new SimpleEmailService('KEY', 'KEY');
$m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
$m->addTo('mail@gmail.com');
$m->setFrom('Test Support <test@test.com>');
$m->setSubject('Hello, world!');
$m->setMessageFromString($body);
print_r($ses->sendEmail($m));
```

This code pretty working well and I am confused how to send a HTML formatted mail through this script.

A body like this

```
$body='<div ><b>Name</b></div>';
```

Any one please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: `$m->setMessageFromString($body);`

Comment: If it works, then I don't understand your question. Your `$body` can be from any HTML, whether it be static in a variable or from a file open/parse.

Comment: I tried this with a simple HTML format as $body ... But getting HTML as plain text ( can see the HTML code ) in that email.. Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping <html> tags around it to say that it is HTML?

Comment: Yes.. But not working ... see my code updated

Comment: if you used css with html, then plz give me an example how i can do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok think I have found the system you are using and it doesnt look like the standard SES api.

Try

```
$m->setMessageFromString($plainTextBody,$HTMLBody);
```

Where you have the plain text version and html version of your emails defined in `$plainTextBody` and `$HTMLBody` before that line.

Comment: how i can use css with html in this?

Comment: @BSThakrar E-mail doesn't support CSS through external stylesheets or <style> tags, but you can use inline styles such as `<p style="font-weight: bold; color: red">This is bold red text</p>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-php.html)
 then do this to send html emails with css

```
$request['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = $to;
```

That is replace the **Text** key with **Html**